# Original source of the term "Siaynoq"?

Tags: dune, frank-herbert

Re-reading the Dune novels, and I remembered an old question:

What is the source of the term "Siaynoq" as found in God Emperor of Dune?

Most of the non-english terms in the Dune universe come from languages like old Hebrew, Farsi, Arabic, Latin, etc.  But i can't seem to nail down this one term.

I'm not looking for the in-universe definition.

Comment: It looks more Native American than anything.  But I don't know whether it really is or exactly which language it would be and what it would mean if so, or what that would be doing there (I haven't read that book).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

sihanouk means Jaws of the Lion in Sanskrit......

Comment: you're welcome.  I don't know that's what he used, I know zero Arabic, and my husband figured this out, not me, but I figured I'd share.  He says, "or the Jaws of the Worm?"

Comment: Herbert used a lot of languages in the books, I think it's reasonable that he cribbed from Sanscrit considering the religious nature of the rite.

Comment: For what it's worth, "sihanouk" ‌does not mean anything in Sanskrit. (Well, the closest is perhaps "siṃha" which means "lion", and "hanu"‌ which means "jaw", so perhaps "siṃhahanu" could mean "lion-jaw", but "sihanouk" is not a Sanskrit term.)

Comment: Apparently it's Pali, not Sanskrit.

Answer (score 2):

There is this one interesting post found [here](http://www.jacurutu.com/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=1554#p54556) that says the following:

> It says the ritual goes back to the earliest Zensunni, and stems from
>   event called "Siayla" meaning "the Light of truth" they gathered and
>   discussed the progress toward the religious goals of the year.

Considering that the Zensunni are a mixture between zen buddhism and sunni islam, `siayla` sounds more arabic to me. Also, on [the Wikipedia page for the Dune religions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Dune_religions), there is this part:

> Terminology of the Imperium also defines several Zensunni terms:
>
> AULIYA: In the Zensunni Wanderers' religion, the female at the left
>   hand of God; God's handmaiden.(...)
>
> These concepts are all more or less identifiable with Islamic
>   concepts: *Auliya* (Arabic: أولياء) is the Arabic word for saints

Auliya sounds very much like Siayla to me so I guess it's very likely to be an arabic term.

Comment: This is the in-universe explanation, and I'm looking for the out-of-universe linguistic source.

Answer (score 2):

I just came across the name of a Cambodian King, **Norodom Sihanouk**(1922-2012) and was struck by how similar his name is to Leto's ritual. In Cambodia, he is known as Samdech Euv (meaning "King Father"). He led the country for many years as King, Prime Minister, then later as King again under a restored monarchy.

I think it's possible Herbert would have heard of him since he was leader during the Cambodian civil war and rule of the Khmer Rouge which were major news stories at the time he wrote the book. Not 100%, but this is my best guess.

> The name Sihanouk is derived from Sanskrit through two Pali words: siha ('lion'), and hanu ('jaws').

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You forgot to provide a link to the web page you quoted in your answer, though.